# Starting with test unit in NodeJS

Tags: automated-testing

There are probably other similar questions on SE but I couldn't find them. I am currently researching techs available to make unit test on my server. I have no experience at all with any kind of unit testing. I've looked around on the net, and managed to find some information about what exists and how it works, but there are a lot of options it seems. I don't have the time to learn and try each of them to see what suits me best.

I would like some words of people who have experience with these technologies, to tell me which is their preferred (and why), if there is any better alternatives and if my broad understanding of their roles is not completely flawed.

- SuperTest, Should, Expect, which run asserts on individual part of the tested code.
- Mocha which organise those tests.
- Jenkins and TeamCity, who automatise the Mocha script (and other things) Not sure about TeamCity, but I'd like to use it since it can work along other Jetbrains product that I am already using.

Answer (score 1):

> SuperTest, Should, Expect, which run asserts on individual part of the tested code.

It depends on your taste ;).
IMHO, mocha + chai - nice choice

> Mocha which organizes those tests.

Mocha does not organize your tests. You organize your tests whatever you like. Mocha gives you API to write tests. Nothing more

> Jenkins and TeamCity, who automatise the Mocha script (and other things) Not sure about TeamCity, but I'd like to use it since it can work along other Jetbrains product that I am already using.

It doesn`t matter what CI server you have. The difference only in special configurations for CI server. These configurations help you to run tests in headless mode.